# Setting HTTP request header for all types of request in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, http-headers

I am trying to figure out a way to send data from the browser to the server without storing it. I don't want to use a cookie.

The value is produced on the browser via javascript and I want it to be submitted with all the HTTP requests, for all methods (GET, PATCH, POST, DELETE).

I know I should probably provide some code of what I've done so far, but everything I've tried ended up to a "bump". I'm as blind as when I started looking.

I am using `jQuery` in my app, for all that this might be useful.

It has proven easy to do with ajax requests, but I want all types of requests.

I'm approaching the conclusion that the nature of what I want to do is apparently evil and, hence, not allowed by the relevant RFC's. My intentions are not evil at all, for the record.

Comment: Maybe you could describe what are you trying to achieve? Because it looks like you're trying to hammer a nail with a screwdriver or something.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `jQuery.ajaxSetup()` method. It allows you to set default values for all Ajax requests. You can find more about it here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup

The options/settings that you can provide to **ajaxSetup** are the same as in **jQuery.ajax()** - more info here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Here is an example that sets the **X-CSRF-Token** header for ajax requests:

```
$.ajaxSetup( {
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
  }
});
```

Here is another way of doing the same thing:

```
$.ajaxSetup( {
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') 
  }
});
```

Please note that you have to execute the examples above before making any actual requests.

### Edit:

Regarding the **X-CSRF-Token** header, if you are using jQuery with the `jquery-rails` gem this happens automatically. More here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CsrfHelper/csrf_meta_tags

### Update:

I must have misread your question; sorry about that! The solution I provided is specifically for Ajax requests. In JavaScript, HTTP basically means Ajax.

If you're concerned with all client side requests, including Ajax, form submissions,
clicking links, typing in the URL bar, asset requests for things like `<img>` and `<script>` tags, etc., you have to save a cookie in the Browser for a value to be available on every HTTP request.

If you don't want to store anything on the client-side, then you are certainly out of luck because that kind of magic simply doesn't exist. It's like asking: *How can I fly, but without an airplane or any other man-made device?* At least that's how I interpret your question based on the information you've provided.